# Thesaurus for programming keywords

Tags: terminology

Imagine having a TheSaurus for programming language Keywords and Concepts that responds to queryes with synonyms and antonyms that are strictly other language keywords or operands.
Asking for ">=" the user will be presented with "<=" as antonym and ">" as a synonym (it's an example).
Which Antonym will you expect to find searching for the term "for each"?

If this is OT let me know.
I'm not so at pace with the community since years.

Comment: "for none"? Doesn't seem useful. No code required. :-p

Comment: I'd say "select case" but my collegues disagree.

Comment: Joking aside, I don't understand the point or context of the question.

Comment: i've edited it. hope that's clearer.

Comment: I've thought of this problem before - it would be useful to have some kind of cross-reference for equivalent functions in different languages. Rosettacode.org might be relevant, then. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For each" wouldn't have an antonym. Your question reminds me of this other riddle: "What is the opposite of a circle?"

Answer (score 6):

The antonym for `foreach` would be `fornone`, but since that wouldn't be very useful you wouldn't find it in any programming language, unless you count things like Python's `pass` or a `NOOP`.

However the `while`-loop can be a synonym for `foreach` in some contexts and the `while` loop does have a direct antonym with the `until`-loop (available in Ruby, Bash and Lisp). Similarly there exist an antonym for the `if` statement with the `unless` statement.

I am not aware of any reasonably complete Programmer Thesaurus that could answer such and similar questions, however there are a few projects on Github that might act as a starting point:

- https://github.com/tindzk/thesaurus
- https://github.com/wobh/lexicode
- https://github.com/imightbeinatree/what_the_function